# Ruby gem to parse xlsx cell contents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I have an Excel document. Each cell will contain an Image as well as text. I want extract text and Image separately and store it in ruby variables.

But I am not finding a Gem which will do the Job.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

'spreadsheet' gem is best for parsing Excel documents

Comment: Does it support retrieval of graphical objects(images, charts etc) ? Can u paste here sample code ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [roo](http://rubygems.org/gems/roo). Sample usage can be found in the [documentation](http://rubydoc.info/gems/roo/1.11.2/frames). I used it for getting text contents of a cell though I haven't tried it for images.

Comment: I think graphics type is not supported by roo gem.. Do u know any other gem ?